# mpt3sas_scsih_issue_tm: timeout when doing ZFS scrub

Tags: linux, centos, storage, zfs, sas

## Overview

We are currently doing a scrub on a ZFS pool with 12 RAID-Z1 vdevs, and each vdev has 12 drives. Each vdev corresponds to an enclosure. The hardware is a Dell PowerEdge 730xd with two Dell 12Gbps SAS (LSI SAS3008) controllers, and 12 Dell MD1400 enclosures. The operating system is CentOS 7.6.1810.

We have not been able to successfully scrub the pool, because after some time drives become `FAULTED` in ZFS, and we must `zpool clear` to continue. The drives that become `FAULTED` are seemingly random, and `smartctl` says their SMART status is okay.

The only commonality is that before the drives are marked `FAULTED`, the error message `mpt3sas_scsih_issue_tm: timeout` appears in `dmesg`, followed by the controller resetting, and a flood of ZED errors amd read errors.

I am currently stuck on the following:

- Is this a software or hardware issue?
- If it's software, is there a configuration change or patch that can prevent the error?
- If it's hardware, how can I narrow the issue down?

## What We've Tried

We've tried the following:

- Increasing the timeout values for each disk at `/sys/block/*/device/timeout`
- Replacing all of the SAS cables
- Upgrading all of the firmware
- Running the SMART background long test on the `FAULTED` disk
- Rebooting (3 times so far)

I also looked at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1343367/lsi-9211-8i-error-mpt2sas-cm0-mpt3sas-scsih-issue-tm-timeout-filesystem-di) but it didn't help.

## Details

Here's `journalctl` from when the event begins:

```
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: attempting task abort! scmd(ffff8d36c295a4c0)
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:4:0: attempting task abort! scmd(ffff8d3745b20540)
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:4:0: [sdac] CDB: Read(32)
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:4:0: [sdac] CDB[00]: 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 09 20 00 00 00 00 00
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:4:0: [sdac] CDB[10]: 60 2a b8 c8 60 2a b8 c8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: scsi target5:0:4: handle(0x000e), sas_address(0x5000c500a6bb846e), phy(4)
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: scsi target5:0:4: enclosure logical id(0x5204747299f56500), slot(4) 
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: scsi target5:0:4: enclosure level(0x0000), connector name( 1   )
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: [sdap] CDB: Read(32)
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: [sdap] CDB[00]: 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 09 20 00 00 00 00 00
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: [sdap] CDB[10]: 60 2b f7 f8 60 2b f7 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: scsi target5:0:18: handle(0x001d), sas_address(0x5000c500a6bb68ce), phy(5)
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: scsi target5:0:18: enclosure logical id(0x5204747299f5dd00), slot(0) 
Apr 12 04:42:07 kernel: scsi target5:0:18: enclosure level(0x0001), connector name( 1   )
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: mpt3sas_scsih_issue_tm: timeout
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: mf:

Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 0100000e 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000100 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 

Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 00000000 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 000000b6 
Apr 12 04:42:37 kernel: 
Apr 12 04:42:47 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: sending diag reset !!
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: diag reset: SUCCESS
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: LSISAS3008: FWVersion(16.00.04.00), ChipRevision(0x02), BiosVersion(18.00.00.00)
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: Protocol=(
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: Initiator
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: ,Target
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: ), 
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: Capabilities=(
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: TLR
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: ,EEDP
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: ,Snapshot Buffer
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: ,Diag Trace Buffer
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: ,Task Set Full
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: ,NCQ
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: )
Apr 12 04:42:48 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: sending port enable !!
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: port enable: SUCCESS
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: search for end-devices: start
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: scsi target5:0:0: handle(0x000a), sas_addr(0x5000c500a6bc5ef6)
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: scsi target5:0:0: enclosure logical id(0x5204747299f56500), slot(9)
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: scsi target5:0:1: handle(0x000b), sas_addr(0x5000c500a6bc6e66)
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: scsi target5:0:1: enclosure logical id(0x5204747299f56500), slot(5)
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: scsi target5:0:2: handle(0x000c), sas_addr(0x5000c500a6bbd86e)
Apr 12 04:42:55 kernel: scsi target5:0:2: enclosure logical id(0x5204747299f56500), slot(1)
```

The `handle` and `enclosure` lines are repeated for every drive attached to the controller.

Then, it's followed by:

```
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: search for end-devices: complete
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: search for expanders: start
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel:         expander present: handle(0x0009), sas_addr(0x5204747299f565ff)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel:         expander present: handle(0x0016), sas_addr(0x5204747299f5ddff)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel:         expander present: handle(0x0024), sas_addr(0x520474729a0a68ff)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel:         expander present: handle(0x0032), sas_addr(0x520474729a0b61ff)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel:         expander present: handle(0x0040), sas_addr(0x520474729a09f1ff)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: search for expanders: complete
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:4:0: task abort: SUCCESS scmd(ffff8d3745b20540)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: removing unresponding devices: start
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: removing unresponding devices: end-devices
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: removing unresponding devices: expanders
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: removing unresponding devices: complete
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: mpt3sas_cm1: scan devices: start
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: task abort: SUCCESS scmd(ffff8d36c295a4c0)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: scsi_io_completion: 13 callbacks suppressed
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: [sdap] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: [sdap] CDB: Read(32)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: [sdap] CDB[00]: 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 09 20 00 00 00 00 00
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:18:0: [sdap] CDB[10]: 60 2b f7 f8 60 2b f7 f8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: blk_update_request: 13 callbacks suppressed
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdap, sector 1613494264
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:21:0: attempting task abort! scmd(ffff8d3acfef0540)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:21:0: [sdas] CDB: Read(32)
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:21:0: [sdas] CDB[00]: 7f 00 00 00 00 00 00 18 00 09 20 00 00 00 00 03
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: sd 5:0:21:0: [sdas] CDB[10]: 01 af 8c b0 01 af 8c b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08
Apr 12 04:42:57 kernel: scsi target5:0:21: handle(0x0020), sas_address(0x5000c500a6bc5f82), phy(8)
```

plus a lot more read timeouts. Then, we see a lot of `zed` errors:

```
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137074]: eid=2425 class=delay pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc59bb-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137076]: eid=2426 class=delay pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc59bb-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137078]: eid=2427 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc59bb-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137080]: eid=2428 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc59bb-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137082]: eid=2429 class=delay pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc4337-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137084]: eid=2430 class=delay pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc4337-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137086]: eid=2431 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc4337-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137088]: eid=2432 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc4337-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137090]: eid=2433 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137092]: eid=2434 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137094]: eid=2435 class=delay pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc5f83-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137096]: eid=2436 class=delay pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc5f83-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137098]: eid=2437 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc5f83-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137100]: eid=2438 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bc5f83-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137102]: eid=2439 class=delay pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bb68cf-part1
Apr 12 04:42:57 zed[137104]: eid=2440 class=io pool_guid=0x3317CEBDDE480DA0 vdev_path=/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-35000c500a6bb68cf-part1
```

After that, the drives are marked DEGRADED or FAULTED. I'll also include some more information that might be helpful.

Here is the output of `zpool status` for the two vdevs with `FAULTED` devices:

```
    raidz1-4                                         DEGRADED     0     0     0
      scsi-35000cca2513f78b8                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca25157bfd0                         ONLINE       0     0     0  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca251597aa4                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2515de7b0                         FAULTED      0     0     0  too many errors
      scsi-35000cca2516278c8                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors
      scsi-35000cca25163ea64                         ONLINE       0     0     0  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca251644664                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2516576a0                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors
      scsi-35000cca251699f68                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca25169bd10                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca25169be5c                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca25169c09c                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
    raidz1-5                                         DEGRADED     0     0     0
      scsi-35000cca2516bc234                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2516bc26c                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      scsi-35000cca2516c8e78                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      scsi-35000cca2516ca244                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      scsi-35000cca2516ca334                         ONLINE       0     0     0  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2516ca848                         ONLINE       0     0     0  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2516cb3e0                         ONLINE       0     0     0  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2516cb420                         DEGRADED     0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2516cc210                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      scsi-35000cca2516ce390                         FAULTED      0     0     0  too many errors  (repairing)
      scsi-35000cca2516ce8e4                         ONLINE       0     0     0
      scsi-35000cca2516cf224                         ONLINE       0     0     0
```

Here is the output of `smartctl -a` for the `FAULTED` drive in `raidz1-4`:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HGST
Product:              HUH721010AL5200
Revision:             LS15
Compliance:           SPC-4
User Capacity:        9,796,820,402,176 bytes [9.79 TB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Physical block size:  4096 bytes
Formatted with type 2 protection
LU is fully provisioned
Rotation Rate:        7200 rpm
Form Factor:          3.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000cca2515de7b0
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS (SPL-3)
Local Time is:        Fri Apr 12 13:40:57 2019 CDT
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     29 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        50 C

Manufactured in week 02 of year 2017
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  50000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  5
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  600000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  889
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 30677043943309312

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0       40         0       294   10394513     118610.223           0
write:         0        0         0         0     239773      43528.082           0
verify:        0        0         0         0      18403        101.563           0

Non-medium error count:        0

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background long   Completed                  96   18243                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                  96   16753                 - [-   -    -]
# 3  Reserved(7)       Completed                  64       2                 - [-   -    -]

Long (extended) Self Test duration: 64033 seconds [1067.2 minutes]
```

`sysctl -a | grep -v 'net.' | grep -v 'kernel.sched_domain.'`:

```
abi.vsyscall32 = 1
crypto.fips_enabled = 0
debug.exception-trace = 1
debug.kprobes-optimization = 1
debug.panic_on_rcu_stall = 0
dev.hpet.max-user-freq = 64
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button2_keycode = 97
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button3_keycode = 100
dev.mac_hid.mouse_button_emulation = 0
dev.raid.speed_limit_max = 200000
dev.raid.speed_limit_min = 1000
dev.scsi.logging_level = 0
fs.aio-max-nr = 65536
fs.aio-nr = 0
fs.binfmt_misc.status = enabled
fs.dentry-state = 235028  190450  45  0 0 0
fs.dir-notify-enable = 1
fs.epoll.max_user_watches = 108185722
fs.file-max = 52384239
fs.file-nr = 2080 0 52384239
fs.inode-nr = 102807  662
fs.inode-state = 102807 662 0 0 0 0 0
fs.inotify.max_queued_events = 16384
fs.inotify.max_user_instances = 128
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 8192
fs.lease-break-time = 45
fs.leases-enable = 1
fs.may_detach_mounts = 0
fs.mount-max = 100000
fs.mqueue.msg_default = 10
fs.mqueue.msg_max = 10
fs.mqueue.msgsize_default = 8192
fs.mqueue.msgsize_max = 8192
fs.mqueue.queues_max = 256
fs.nfs.nlm_grace_period = 0
fs.nfs.nlm_tcpport = 0
fs.nfs.nlm_timeout = 10
fs.nfs.nlm_udpport = 0
fs.nfs.nsm_local_state = 3
fs.nfs.nsm_use_hostnames = 0
fs.nr_open = 1048576
fs.overflowgid = 65534
fs.overflowuid = 65534
fs.pipe-max-size = 1048576
fs.pipe-user-pages-hard = 0
fs.pipe-user-pages-soft = 16384
fs.protected_hardlinks = 1
fs.protected_symlinks = 1
fs.quota.allocated_dquots = 0
fs.quota.cache_hits = 0
fs.quota.drops = 0
fs.quota.free_dquots = 0
fs.quota.lookups = 0
fs.quota.reads = 0
fs.quota.syncs = 0
fs.quota.warnings = 1
fs.quota.writes = 0
fs.suid_dumpable = 0
fs.xfs.age_buffer_centisecs = 1500
fs.xfs.error_level = 3
fs.xfs.filestream_centisecs = 3000
fs.xfs.inherit_noatime = 1
fs.xfs.inherit_nodefrag = 1
fs.xfs.inherit_nodump = 1
fs.xfs.inherit_nosymlinks = 0
fs.xfs.inherit_sync = 1
fs.xfs.irix_sgid_inherit = 0
fs.xfs.irix_symlink_mode = 0
fs.xfs.panic_mask = 0
fs.xfs.rotorstep = 1
fs.xfs.speculative_prealloc_lifetime = 300
fs.xfs.stats_clear = 0
fs.xfs.xfsbufd_centisecs = 100
fs.xfs.xfssyncd_centisecs = 3000
kernel.acct = 4 2 30
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
kernel.auto_msgmni = 1
kernel.bootloader_type = 114
kernel.bootloader_version = 2
kernel.cad_pid = 1
kernel.cap_last_cap = 36
kernel.compat-log = 1
kernel.core_pattern = core
kernel.core_pipe_limit = 0
kernel.core_uses_pid = 1
kernel.ctrl-alt-del = 0
kernel.dmesg_restrict = 0
kernel.domainname = (none)
kernel.ftrace_dump_on_oops = 0
kernel.ftrace_enabled = 1
kernel.hardlockup_all_cpu_backtrace = 0
kernel.hardlockup_panic = 1
kernel.hostname = htc-sblock-node197
kernel.hotplug = 
kernel.hung_task_check_count = 4194304
kernel.hung_task_panic = 0
kernel.hung_task_timeout_secs = 120
kernel.hung_task_warnings = 0
kernel.io_delay_type = 0
kernel.kexec_load_disabled = 0
kernel.keys.gc_delay = 300
kernel.keys.maxbytes = 20000
kernel.keys.maxkeys = 200
kernel.keys.persistent_keyring_expiry = 259200
kernel.keys.root_maxbytes = 25000000
kernel.keys.root_maxkeys = 1000000
kernel.kptr_restrict = 0
kernel.max_lock_depth = 1024
kernel.modprobe = /sbin/modprobe
kernel.modules_disabled = 0
kernel.msg_next_id = -1
kernel.msgmax = 8192
kernel.msgmnb = 16384
kernel.msgmni = 32768
kernel.ngroups_max = 65536
kernel.nmi_watchdog = 1
kernel.ns_last_pid = 176562
kernel.numa_balancing = 1
kernel.numa_balancing_scan_delay_ms = 1000
kernel.numa_balancing_scan_period_max_ms = 60000
kernel.numa_balancing_scan_period_min_ms = 1000
kernel.numa_balancing_scan_size_mb = 256
kernel.numa_balancing_settle_count = 4
kernel.osrelease = 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64
kernel.ostype = Linux
kernel.overflowgid = 65534
kernel.overflowuid = 65534
kernel.panic = 0
kernel.panic_on_io_nmi = 0
kernel.panic_on_oops = 1
kernel.panic_on_stackoverflow = 0
kernel.panic_on_unrecovered_nmi = 0
kernel.panic_on_warn = 0
kernel.perf_cpu_time_max_percent = 25
kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate = 32000
kernel.perf_event_mlock_kb = 516
kernel.perf_event_paranoid = 2
kernel.pid_max = 196608
kernel.poweroff_cmd = /sbin/poweroff
kernel.print-fatal-signals = 0
kernel.printk = 7 4 1 7
kernel.printk_delay = 0
kernel.printk_ratelimit = 5
kernel.printk_ratelimit_burst = 10
kernel.pty.max = 4096
kernel.pty.nr = 4
kernel.pty.reserve = 1024
kernel.random.boot_id = 5bd2b4ab-221e-4157-98ad-fe4a81da7784
kernel.random.entropy_avail = 4034
kernel.random.poolsize = 4096
kernel.random.read_wakeup_threshold = 64
kernel.random.urandom_min_reseed_secs = 60
kernel.random.uuid = 4f4a6d22-d974-452d-b550-0e19b7a3c74e
kernel.random.write_wakeup_threshold = 896
kernel.randomize_va_space = 2
kernel.real-root-dev = 0
kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled = 0
kernel.sched_cfs_bandwidth_slice_us = 5000
kernel.sched_child_runs_first = 0
kernel.sched_latency_ns = 24000000
kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 500000
kernel.sched_min_granularity_ns = 3000000
kernel.sched_nr_migrate = 32
kernel.sched_rr_timeslice_ms = 100
kernel.sched_rt_period_us = 1000000
kernel.sched_rt_runtime_us = 950000
kernel.sched_schedstats = 0
kernel.sched_shares_window_ns = 10000000
kernel.sched_time_avg_ms = 1000
kernel.sched_tunable_scaling = 1
kernel.sched_wakeup_granularity_ns = 4000000
kernel.seccomp.actions_avail = kill trap errno trace allow
kernel.seccomp.actions_logged = kill trap errno trace
kernel.sem = 250  32000 32  128
kernel.sem_next_id = -1
kernel.shm_next_id = -1
kernel.shm_rmid_forced = 0
kernel.shmall = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
kernel.shmmni = 4096
kernel.softlockup_all_cpu_backtrace = 0
kernel.softlockup_panic = 0
kernel.spl.hostid = 0
kernel.spl.kmem.slab_kmem_alloc = 0
kernel.spl.kmem.slab_kmem_max = 0
kernel.spl.kmem.slab_kmem_total = 0
kernel.spl.kmem.slab_vmem_alloc = 305947392
kernel.spl.kmem.slab_vmem_max = 732324608
kernel.spl.kmem.slab_vmem_total = 347979264
kernel.spl.version = SPL v0.7.12-1
kernel.stack_tracer_enabled = 0
kernel.sysctl_writes_strict = 1
kernel.sysrq = 16
kernel.tainted = 12289
kernel.threads-max = 4126958
kernel.timer_migration = 1
kernel.traceoff_on_warning = 0
kernel.unknown_nmi_panic = 0
kernel.usermodehelper.bset = 4294967295 31
kernel.usermodehelper.inheritable = 4294967295  31
kernel.version = #1 SMP Fri Feb 1 14:54:57 UTC 2019
kernel.watchdog = 1
kernel.watchdog_cpumask = 0-191
kernel.watchdog_thresh = 10
kernel.yama.ptrace_scope = 0
sunrpc.max_resvport = 1023
sunrpc.min_resvport = 665
sunrpc.nfs_debug = 0x0000
sunrpc.nfsd_debug = 0x0000
sunrpc.nlm_debug = 0x0000
sunrpc.rpc_debug = 0x0000
sunrpc.tcp_fin_timeout = 15
sunrpc.tcp_max_slot_table_entries = 65536
sunrpc.tcp_slot_table_entries = 2
sunrpc.transports = tcp 1048576
sunrpc.transports = udp 32768
sunrpc.transports = tcp-bc 1048576
sunrpc.udp_slot_table_entries = 16
user.max_ipc_namespaces = 2063479
user.max_mnt_namespaces = 2063479
user.max_pid_namespaces = 2063479
user.max_user_namespaces = 0
user.max_uts_namespaces = 2063479
vm.admin_reserve_kbytes = 8192
vm.block_dump = 0
vm.dirty_background_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 10
vm.dirty_bytes = 0
vm.dirty_expire_centisecs = 3000
vm.dirty_ratio = 20
vm.dirty_writeback_centisecs = 500
vm.drop_caches = 0
vm.extfrag_threshold = 500
vm.hugepages_treat_as_movable = 0
vm.hugetlb_shm_group = 0
vm.laptop_mode = 0
vm.legacy_va_layout = 0
vm.lowmem_reserve_ratio = 256 256 32
vm.max_map_count = 65530
vm.memory_failure_early_kill = 0
vm.memory_failure_recovery = 1
vm.min_free_kbytes = 90112
vm.min_slab_ratio = 5
vm.min_unmapped_ratio = 1
vm.mmap_min_addr = 4096
vm.mmap_rnd_bits = 28
vm.mmap_rnd_compat_bits = 8
vm.nr_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_hugepages_mempolicy = 0
vm.nr_overcommit_hugepages = 0
vm.nr_pdflush_threads = 0
vm.numa_zonelist_order = default
vm.oom_dump_tasks = 1
vm.oom_kill_allocating_task = 0
vm.overcommit_kbytes = 0
vm.overcommit_memory = 0
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50
vm.page-cluster = 3
vm.panic_on_oom = 0
vm.percpu_pagelist_fraction = 0
vm.stat_interval = 1
vm.swappiness = 60
vm.user_reserve_kbytes = 131072
vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 100
vm.zone_reclaim_mode = 0
```

Let me know if I can include anything else that would be helpful.

Comment: This is in the realm of _paid_ ZFS consulting from my perspective. We could suggest things to try and test, but given the size of the system and the design, there may be other issues.

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Comment: @ewwhite yes, it turned out that the Dell firmware was out of date compared to the LSI firmware, we updated the firmware and the timeouts stopped happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a *freebie*, since I think the scope of work extends to [paid ZFS consulting](https://github.com/ewwhite/zfs-ha/wiki):

- How are your enclosures cabled?
- You have 12 external JBODs, but no indication that multipath is enabled
- Think about where the disks that go offline are in relation to the enclosures and the zpool
- I would always advocate for a SAS cabling ring topology when working with so many enclosures
- If that's not in place, I'd work towards it
- Your pool should also be comprised of multipath `/dev/mapper` devices in that situation
- Can you show your `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf`?
- Are all disks SAS?

---

Example of SAS multipath cabling:

[image]

Comment: We have 6 enclosures per controller and they are daisy-chained, so only one SAS cable per controller. Yes all of the disks are SAS. No multipath yet, I will figure out why we set it up that way and investigate implementing it. We don't have a `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf`.

Comment: Daisy chain is a really bad design for this. You want SAS rings (see above graphic). If you have nothing in the `/etc/modprobe.d/zfs.conf`, it means NO tuning has been applied to the ZFS system, and you're at a terrible performance disadvantage... especially with so many disks. We can continue this offline, but I think you need more help than the initial reported issue.

Comment: I will communicate that to my leadership and see if we are open to hiring consultants. Thank you for the diagrams.

Comment: @howderek Sure. But give some of my suggestions some thought.